# Display the correct dateformat in dateItem dynamicform smartgwt

Tags: date, smartgwt, date-formatting

I'm taking a record fron a grid to populate some item in a dynamicform. The problem is i cannot display dates in the right format for the form, it keeps displaying then as they are in the grid and whatever i do to format the date is just ignored by SmartGWT. I'm a bit confused. Below you'll find my code. Can anyone help me out?

```
dataTrade = new DateItem();
    dataTrade.setTitle(Nove.getInstance().getConstants().dataTrade());
    dataTrade.setName(RecordEditMovTitUploadDS.DATA_TRADE);
    dataTrade.setWidth(100);        
    dataTrade.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);
    dataTrade.setUseTextField(true);
    String dataT = movTitRecord.getAttribute(ListMovTitByValCodTitDetailDS.DATA_TRADE);
    DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date dateTr = null;
    try{
        dateTr = dateTimeFormat.parse(dataT);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        SC.say("Couldn't parse date");
    }
    DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat2 = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateTra= dateTimeFormat2.format(dateTr);
    //dataTrade.setDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE);
    //dataTrade.setDateFormatter(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE);
    dataTrade.setInputFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dataTrade.setDefaultValue(dateTra);
```

To be more specific in debug the date is correctly formatted, when i pass the value to `setDefaultValue` it is `dd/MM/yyyy` as it should but when i load the page the format is still `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and i cannot understand why...

Answer (score 1):

Uncommenting this line should work:

```
dataTrade.setDateFormatter(DateDisplayFormat.TOEUROPEANSHORTDATE);
```

After adding this line, the date was displaying in the correct format. Also I was able to edit the form and input dates in the format dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Thanks but without any reason it started working as it is, so i don't need any other formatting. However thanks for the aswer.